# ¿ Qué diferencia hay entre prototipos y clases en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, buenas-prácticas

Estoy haciendo el "refactoring" de mi código y decidí crear una clase para tener un cierto orden. Para hacerlo decidí usar los prototipos `objeto.prototype`.

A lo que me pregunto ¿ Qué diferencia tiene el hecho de crear una clase `prototipada` y una clase común?  es decir entre :

```
class persona {        
    constructor(nombre){
       this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    function saludar(){
        return `hola ${this.nombre}!`;
    }
}
```

y

```
function persona(nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

persona.prototype.saludar = function (){
    return `hola ${this.nombre}!`;
}
```

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna diferencia y cual sería mejor utilizar.

Comment: te sugiero leer:https://medium.com/@parsyval/javascript-prototype-vs-class-a7015d5473b

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/932/c%C3%B3mo-crear-emular-una-clase-en-javascript

Comment: La palabra `function`en el primer ejemplo sobra, no compila a menos que la borres

Answer (score 5):

Ambas formas son prácticamente equivalentes, la sintaxis de clases es *azúcar sintáctico* con un leve matiz:

```js
function persona(nombre){
    if (!(this instanceof persona)) {
      console.log('No actúo como constructor');
    }
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

persona.prototype.saludar = function (){
    return `hola ${this.nombre}!`;
}

persona('Juan');
p = new persona('yo');
console.log(p);

class Persona {        
    constructor(nombre){
       this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    saludar(){
        return `hola ${this.nombre}!`;
    }
}

let p2 = new Persona('otro');
console.log(p2);
console.log(p2.saludar());

Persona('fallo');
```

Como puedes ver, una función puede ser un constructor o una función normal a la vez, pero un constructor definido con la sintaxis de clases no puede llamarse como si fuera una función.

Puede parecer una tontería, pero las clases *nativas* de Javascript a menudo usan las funciones constructoras para otras funcionalidades, dependiendo de si usas `new` delante o no:

```js
let p = Number('5'); //parsea un String, como parseFloat
console.log(p.__proto__.constructor.name,typeof p);

let d = new Number('5'); //crea un objeto Number
console.log(d.__proto__.constructor.name,typeof d);
```

Answer (score 4):

Para que te hagas una idea, en JS no existe una herencia de clases, por eso existe `prototype`, que es un método que tienen TODOS los objetos y hace la función de heredar, agregar o modificar metodos de/a un objeto. Si te fijas usaste dos metodos para crear el objeto persona: 
Una clase:

```
class persona {        
   constructor(nombre){
     this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  function saludar(){
    return `hola ${this.nombre};
  }
}
```

y una función:

```
function persona(nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Bien. Las clases fueron implementados no hace mucho al lenguaje de JS, te permiten heredar otras clases con `extends`. Anterior a eso, para simular la herencia utilizaban `prototype`. Es el ejemeplo que hiciste aqui:

```
persona.prototype.saludar = function (){
   return "hola "+ this.nombre +"!";
}
```

Estas diciendo que el objeto persona tiene un método que se llama saludar y claramente lo podriamos llamar con

```
var p = new persona("Ivan");
console.log(p.saludar()); //te devolveria el saludo
console.log(p.apellido); //no hay propiedad con ese metodo
```

Espero que te sirva mi explicación!

Answer (score 3):

Antiguamente JavaScript no tenía una forma de crear clases, para ello se usaban los [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/prototype#Especificaciones), Esto cambió en la versión [ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes#Especificaciones)

De igual forma ambos funciona para hacer lo mismo (definir una clase para este ejemplo), como lo explica [@PabloLozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/236940/28035),

---

Ahora el Prototype se usa mas para hacer [Programacion Funcional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_funcional)